# Connect PHP on Linux server to MS SQL on remote server running Windows

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

Im having real trouble getting this to work. I have got the mssql-connect drivers set up and working on the Linux server, it now understands that function and does not return any errors.

I have had our server management team configure the windows server to allow the connection from the linux server. They have tested this and confirm it is all working, however I just cant seem to connect to it with PHP.

I have tried various connection strings, but it won't connect, here is an example

```
<?php
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$server = '214.133.182.71,1443';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, '****', '******');

if (!$link) {
die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
?>
```

I always get:
Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: 214.133.182.71,1443 in /home/v3rec/public_html/test.php on line 10
Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL

The username and password of that for the MS SQL database. Ive tried it with and without the port name. I am running SQL 2012, im not sure what the instance name would be? Am I missing something? Why is PHP unable to connect?

Comment: Instead of printing `"Something went wrong"`, try doing: `print_r(error_get_last()); die;`.

Comment: Didnt give me any more into other than cant connect :(

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but try this: `$server = '214.133.182.71:1443';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest you use PDO and do this:

```
$dbhost  = "myhost";
$dbport  = 10060;
$dbname  = "tempdb";
$dbuser  = "dbuser";
$dbpass  = "password";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO ("dlib:host=$dbhost:$dbport;dbname=$dbname","$dbuser","$dbpass");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: A cant use PDO on Linux only window server

Comment: @WebblyBrown: You can use PDO on Linux (at least I'm pretty sure you can, I don't see why not).  You just need to make sure the `PDO` and `PDO_MSSQL` (may be called `PDO_DBLIB`) extensions are installed and enabled.

Comment: I will take a look into other drivers, this looks promising http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php

Comment: You definitely CAN use PDO on Linux.  It's all I use and I'm on Linux.

Comment: Hmm ive installed the pdo odbc driver above and I still get Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver

Comment: Can you post your connection string?

Comment: in addition, can you yourself validate that you can connect by trying to connect from the command line:  mysql -h <ip> -u <user> -p dbname

Comment: It was the driver I had installed wrong, i installed the one here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160 and I now have it working